# Slow code when connecting to Outlook calendar

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook

I wrote this code and I have two problems with it:

1. Its way too slow
2. It shows only recurring appointments in the calendar. I want it to show not just the recurring appointments from a specific date, but also all the other appointments from that date and only from the date specified.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void GetAllCalendarItems()
        {
            try
            {
               // outlook application object
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                //folder in outlook
                Outlook.Folders OutlookFolders = oApp.Session.Folders;

                //Mapi folder object
                Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder = null;
                // outlook exploer object
                Outlook.Explorer explorer = null;
                //Map subfolder object
                Outlook.MAPIFolder SubFolder = null;

                // folder int control
                int Folderctr;
                // sub folder control
                int subFolderctr;                  

                // initialize base objects

                //date range to get appointments
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime end = start.AddDays(5);

                // loop throught the PST files added on Outlook
                for (Folderctr = 1; Folderctr <= OutlookFolders.Count; Folderctr++)
                {
                    Folder = OutlookFolders[Folderctr];
                    Console.WriteLine("first name of folder " +Folder.Name);
                    explorer = Folder.GetExplorer();
                    //loop throught the folders in the PST files
                    for (subFolderctr = 1; subFolderctr <= explorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Count; subFolderctr++)
                    {
                        SubFolder = explorer.CurrentFolder.Folders[subFolderctr];

                        if (SubFolder.Name == "SCE_Calendar")
                        {
                            GetAllCalendarItems(SubFolder);    

                            Console.WriteLine("subfolder name of folder " + SubFolder.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //close applciation
                oApp.Quit();
                // release com object
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp);
                oApp = null;
            }    
            //Simple error handling.
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            } 
        }

        public void GetAllCalendarItems(Outlook.MAPIFolder seCal)
        {
            Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null; 
           //set recursion to true
            outlookCalendarItems = seCal.Items;
            outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;  
            DateTime last;
            DateTime first;

            foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
            {
                Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp = item.GetRecurrencePattern();
                first = new DateTime(2012, 2, 1, item.Start.Hour, item.Start.Minute, 0);
                last = new DateTime(2012, 2, 29);
                Outlook.AppointmentItem recur = null;

                for (DateTime cur = first; cur <= last; cur = cur.AddDays(1))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur);
                        //Console.WriteLine(recur.Subject + " -> " + cur.ToLongDateString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + recur.Body);
                        Console.WriteLine("Organizer: " + recur.Organizer);
                        Console.WriteLine("Start: " + recur.Start.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("End: " + recur.End.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Location: " + recur.Location);
                        Console.WriteLine("Recurring: " + recur.IsRecurring);
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                        //Show the item to pause.
                    }
                    catch
                    { }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetAllCalendarItems();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting all your code and asking for help improving it isn't really a constructive question. I would suggest refining your question to show the sections of code that are causing you problems and provide a detailed description of the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I use to get Outlook Appointments.  I've pulled it out of a working program, so I may be missing a helper function but this should help get you started.

```
private List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> GetOutlookAppointments(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    var app = outlook.Application;
    var appSession = app.Session;
    var calendar = appSession.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    string filter = String.Format("[Start] >= {0} And [End] < {1}", start.ToString("ddddd h:nn AMPM"), end.ToString("ddddd h:nn AMPM"));
    var items = calendar.Items;
    items.Restrict(filter);
    items.IncludeRecurrences = true;

    Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment;
    var appointments = new List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        appointment = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        if (appointment != null && !appointment.AllDayEvent && (appointment.BusyStatus != Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olOutOfOffice))
        {
            if (appointment.IsRecurring)
            {
                AddReoccuringAppointments(appointments, start, end, appointment);
            }
            else if (appointment.Start >= start && appointment.End < end)
            {   
                appointments.Add(appointment);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void AddReoccuringAppointments(List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> appointments, DateTime start, DateTime end, Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment)
{
    Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp = appointment.GetRecurrencePattern();
    if (rp.PatternStartDate >= end || rp.PatternEndDate <= start) { return; }
    if (rp.PatternStartDate > start)
    {
        start = rp.PatternStartDate;
    }
    if (rp.PatternEndDate < end)
    {
        end = rp.PatternEndDate;
    }

    var exceptions = GetExceptions(rp, start, end);

    Outlook.AppointmentItem recur = null;
    Outlook.Exception exception = null;
    for (DateTime cur = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day, appointment.Start.Hour, appointment.Start.Minute, 0); cur <= end; cur = cur.AddDays(1))
    {
        if ((((int)rp.DayOfWeekMask) & (int)Math.Pow(2,(int)cur.DayOfWeek)) == 0) { continue; }
        exception = exceptions.FirstOrDefault(e => e.OriginalDate.Date == cur.Date);
        if (exception == null)
        {
            recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur);
        }
        else if (!exception.Deleted)
        {
            recur = exception.AppointmentItem;
        }

        if (recur != null)
        {
            appointments.Add(recur);
        }
    }
}

private static List<Outlook.Exception> GetExceptions(Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<Outlook.Exception> exceptions = new List<Outlook.Exception>();
    foreach (Outlook.Exception e in rp.Exceptions)
    {
        if (e.OriginalDate >= start && e.OriginalDate < end)
        {
            exceptions.Add(e);
        }
    }
    return exceptions;
}
```